# Question on AdventureWorks DB...What is the point of rowguid in a lot of the tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008, constraints, adventureworks

So I think I already know the answer to this question...

Running AdventureWorks2008 (latest version) on mssql server 2008. I am thinking that the rowguid column in a lot of the tables is to ensure that there is a primary key. I am probably dead wrong as the column appears to be a constraint.

Correct me if I am wrong and also please correct me with an answer I can learn from. Am just surveying this so far in SQL Management Studio...are there any queries that will back up how wrong I am? I am not a DBA so I am lost :)

Comment: Dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482919/question-on-adventureworks-db-what-is-the-point-of-rowguid-in-a-lot-of-the-tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the rowguid column is used in replication, if you start to use replication the rowguid column will be created. From Books On Line

> Merge replication requires that each
>   published table have a ROWGUID column.
>   If a ROWGUID column does not exist in
>   the table before the Snapshot Agent
>   creates the initial snapshot files,
>   the agent must first add and populate
>   the ROWGUID column. To gain a
>   performance advantage when generating
>   and applying snapshots during merge
>   replication, create the ROWGUID column
>   on each table published during merge
>   replication. When creating the column,
>   specify:
>
> The column title as ROWGUID.
>
> The data type as UNIQUEIDENTIFIER.
>
> The default as NEWID().
>
> The ROWGUIDCOL property.
>
> An index on the column. The ROWGUID
>   column is used frequently for relating
>   to merge tracking data during tracking
>   and synchronization of changes made at
>   the Publisher and at Subscribers.

Comment: OH...I should have known that...I feel like a dumbass with my many MCSE renewals. HRM!